# Constant expression not representable in type 'UInteger'

Tags: c#, vb.net, constant-expression

If I run the following code in C# then it runs fine

```
UInt32 a
a = 0x9E3779B9
```

But when I run the same code in VB.Net then it gives me error "Constant expression not representable in type 'UInteger'"

```
Dim a As UInt32
a = &H9E3779B9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put UI at the end

```
a = &H9E3779B9UI
```

Check this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/88322/uinteger-doesnt-react-the-same-on-decimal-and-hex-values)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> You can follow a prefixed literal with a literal type character. The
>   following example shows this.

```
Dim counter As Short = &H8000S
Dim flags As UShort = &H8000US
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve you problem by viewing [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/88322/uinteger-doesnt-react-the-same-on-decimal-and-hex-values) link
see the workarounds section in this link

Just add "UI" to the end of the literal:

```
      Dim x as UInteger = &HF2894233UI
```

Otherwise &H returns a signed Integer